# How does Smalltalk manipulate call stack frames (thisContext)?

Tags: smalltalk, callstack, continuations, stack-frame

The Smalltalk object `thisContext` look strange and marvelous. I can't understand what it is and how it works. And even how it enables continuations.

For C's call-stack, I can easily imagine how is it implemented and working. But for this... I can't. Please help me to understand it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is not an easy question. The stack is reified in the image with instances of MethodContext. A MethodContext can have a sender, which is another MethodContext. That one can have another one...generating a whole stack. MethodContext are instantiated by the VM while executing CompiledMethod (which are also reified in the language).

How MethodContext are mapped to C stack, that depends on the VM. StackVM (CogVM is on top of StackVM) is exactly a VM that better maps MethodContext con C stack.

Apart from the BlueBook that Lukas said, check

http://www.mirandabanda.org/cogblog/   check on the left the posts...

I recommend you to ask in http://lists.squeakfoundation.org/mailman/listinfo/vm-dev

Comment: Thanks for answer. Currently, the blue book is saying many things to me :)

Answer (score 4):

The best explanation you can find in [Smalltalk-80: The Language and its Implementation](http://stephane.ducasse.free.fr/FreeBooks/BlueBook/Bluebook.pdf), Chapter 26 to 30. The stack frames (contexts) are explained on page 580.

Answer (score 3):

It's more correct to say that `thisContext` *is* a continuation - the current continuation, in particular.

Imagine a variable `c` that, just before a `MethodContext` activates, is set to point to that context. That's `thisContext`.

Comment: Thanks for answer. It's hard time to me because I couldn't fully understand implementation of continuation itself yet...